# Como pegar os eventos de um drag e passar para variaveis php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css3, drag-n-drop

Eu tenho esse projeto abaixo.

Nele eu tenho uma lista de imagens onde posso arrastar e sotar da forma que precisar.
Até ai esta funcionando corretamente da forma que preciso.
Preciso considerar a posição das imagens como uma ordem, exemplo:

```
img1 = posição 1
img2 = posição 2
img3 = posição 3 e assim sucessivamente ....
```

Após o usário arrastar e organizar da forma que ele achar melhor,preciso pegar a localização das imagens para que seja salva em um banco de dados e  da próxima vez que ele acessar as imagens estarem na posição de como ele deixou salvo.

Ou seja preciso conseguir pegar esses eventos e salvar em variáveis do php para que possa salvar no mysql, como poderia estar fazendo isso ?

Imagino que o resultado que preciso seria algo como:

```
img1 = posição 2
img2 = posição 1
img3 = posição 3 e assim sucessivamente ....
```

```js
/*!
 * grabbable
 * Version: 1.0.4
 *
 * Copyright 2016 Wolfgang Kurz
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/WolfgangKurz/grabbable
 */
"use strict";
!function(){
 var grabbableStyle = function(){
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.type = "text/css";
  style.innerHTML = ".grabbable > * { -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab } "
   + ".grabbable > .grabbable-dummy {"
   + " border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;"
   + " background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #fff, #fff 4px, #d4d4d4 4px, #d4d4d4 5px );"
   + "}";
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(style);
 };
 var callCallback = function(elem){
  if(document.createEventObject) {
   elem.fireEvent("ondragged");
  } else {
   var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
   evt.initEvent("dragged", false, true);
   elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
 };

 var dummy = null, bg = null;
 var createDummy = function(){
  bg = document.createElement("div");
  bg.style.position = "absolute";
  bg.style.width = "1px";
  bg.style.height = "1px";
  bg.style.overflow = "hidden";

  dummy = document.createElement("div");
  dummy.className = "grabbable-dummy";
  dummy.style.position = "relative";
  dummy.addEventListener("drop", function(e){
   var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   if(data!="draggable") return;

   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();

   while(bg.children.length>0){
    var elem = bg.children[0];
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, this);
   }

   dummy.style.display = "none";
   callCallback(dummy.parentNode);
  });

  var x = document.querySelector("body");
  x.appendChild(dummy);
  x.appendChild(bg);
 };
 var updateDummy = function(el){
  bg.style.left = el.offsetLeft+"px";
  bg.style.top = el.offsetTop+"px";
  dummy.style.width = el.offsetWidth+"px";
  dummy.style.height = el.offsetHeight+"px";

  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  dummy.style.display = style.display;
  dummy.style.margin = style.marginTop+" "+style.marginRight+" "+style.marginBottom+" "+style.marginLeft;
  dummy.style.padding = style.paddingTop+" "+style.paddingRight+" "+style.paddingBottom+" "+style.paddingLeft;
 };
 var initGrabbable = function(){
  grabbableStyle();
  createDummy();
 };

 var prevent = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 };
 var allowDrop = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  e.stopPropagation();

  if(this.previousElementSibling!=dummy)
   this.parentNode.insertBefore(dummy, this);
  else
   this.parentNode.insertBefore(dummy, this.nextElementSibling);
 }
 var dragOn = function(e){
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", "draggable");
 };
 var resetDrop = function(e){
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if(data!="draggable") return;

  prevent(e);

  while(bg.children.length>0){
   var elem = bg.children[0];
   dummy.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, dummy);
  }
  dummy.style.display = "none";
  callCallback(dummy.parentNode);
 };

 if(document.readyState=="complete") initGrabbable();
 else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ initGrabbable() });

 HTMLElement.prototype.grabbable = function(){
  if( (" "+this.className+" ").indexOf(" grabbable ")<0 )
   this.className += " grabbable";

  for(var i=0; i<this.children.length; i++){
   var el = this.children[i];
   if(typeof el.draggabled=="undefined"){
    if(el==dummy) continue;

    el.draggable = true;

    el.addEventListener("dragstart", dragOn);
    el.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
    el.addEventListener("drag", function(){
     if(this.parentNode==bg) return;
     if(this==dummy) return;

     updateDummy(this);
     this.parentNode.insertBefore(dummy, this);
     bg.appendChild(this);
    });
    el.addEventListener("drop", function(e){
     prevent(e);

     if(document.createEventObject) dummy.fireEvent("ondrop", e);
     else dummy.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent(e.type, e));
    });
    el.draggabled = true;
   }
  }

  if(typeof document.draggabled=="undefined"){
   document.addEventListener("dragover", prevent);
   document.addEventListener("drop", resetDrop);
   document.draggabled = true;
  }
 };
}()
    "use strict";
    !function(){
     document.querySelector(".grabbable-parent1")
     .grabbable();
 }()
```

```css
       * { box-sizing: border-box }
        .box {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #da251d;
        }
        .listaProduto {
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden;     
        }
        .listaProduto figure figcaption {
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            z-index:5;
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box
        }
        .listaProduto figure p {
            font-family:'Lato';
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size:30px; 
        }
        .listaProduto figure p {
            font-family:'Lato';
            font-size:20px;
            line-height:18px;
            margin:0;
            color:#ffffff; 
        }
        .listaProduto figure figcaption {
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:rgba(26,76,110,0.5);
            text-align:center;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
            transform:rotateY(-180deg);
            -webkit-transition:all .5s;
            -moz-transition:all .5s;
            transition:all .5s
        }
        .listaProduto figure img {
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            -webkit-transition:all .5s;
            -moz-transition:all .5s;
            transition:all .5s
        }
        .listaProduto figure:hover img,figure.hover img {
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
            -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
            transform:rotateY(180deg)
        }
        .listaProduto figure:hover figcaption,figure.hover figcaption {
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(0);
            -moz-transform:rotateY(0);
            transform:rotateY(0)
        }
```

```html
    <div class="box grabbable-parent1">
      <div class="listaProduto">
        <figure>
        <img src="https://static.wmobjects.com.br/imgres/arquivos/ids/7837271-344-344/leve-4-pague-3-toalhas-umedecidas-48-unidades-huggies---total-192-unidades.jpg" width="50" height="50">
            <figcaption>
             <h3>
                <p>PRODUTO 01</p>
                <p>R$20.00</p>
            </h3>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/10/headerdesk.png" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 02</p>
            <p>R$20.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/11/0.3814740014630907401.png" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 03</p>
            <p>R$30.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/09/carta-branca.png" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 04</p>
            <p>R$40.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/08/04005500073727.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 05</p>
            <p>R$50.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/09/nononono_2000030.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 06</p>
            <p>R$60.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/10/figura-1frente-1.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 07</p>
            <p>R$70.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://supermercadosnogueira.com.br/wp-content/uploads/supermercadosnogueira/2016/10/whiskas-lata-carne-500x500.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 08</p>
            <p>R$80.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<div class="listaProduto">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.goiasverde.com.br/produtos-img-alta/molho-de-tomate-bolonhesa-4412.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <figcaption>
         <h3>
            <p>PRODUTO 09</p>
            <p>R$90.00</p>
        </h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sim,tenta atribuir um id unico a cada produto, depois guardas o id num array a cada evento que utilizador executar, e depois faz uma requisição ajax para guardares o array , e ja guarda pela ordem que o utilizador escolheu

Comment: Não seria melhor guardar num localStorage em vez de banco de dados? Assim não precisaria de requisições ao servidor nem de banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em um projeto faço exatamento o que tu quer vou mostrar:

```
 $(".draggable").each( function(elem) {

   $(this).draggable({

    appendTo:'body',
    scroll:true,
    containment: 'window',
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    stop: function(){
var ind= $(this).attr("indimg");
var top = $(this).css('top');
var left = $(this).css('left');
var width1 = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
var height1 = parseInt($(this).css('height'));
var pagina = "<?= $_GET['pagina'] ?>";
var position = [ind,top,left,width1,height1,pagina];
}
});
```

No momento que é solto o elemento tu pega todas as informações dele, essas informações tu pode passar para uma pagina php que salvara no banco atraves de ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    asynnc: true,
    url:"salvabanco.php",
   data:"posicao="+position,
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
    }
});
```

mais sobre o json e ajax caso precise:
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.json.php
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!